# 日本語に違和感: 「クリックして読み込んでください」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

対象: 裏で更新のあった質問

スクショ:

[image: クリックして読み込んでください]

> この投稿は編集されました。クリックして読み込んでください

この投稿は編集されました。クリックして再読み込みしてください

あまり大差ないかもしれませんが「再読み込み」の方が一般的なように思います。

Answer (score 2):

翻訳を変えましたので、次回のビルドに適用します。